# Delete records from excel sheet data source based on number of columns a record has

Tags: excel, ssis

I have an excel sheet with 230000 records in it.Basically my data source has 54 columns. But for few records (due to the wrong extraction of data from SQL server into Excel Sheet) it has more than 54 columns.

I wanted to clean those bad records based on number of columns a record has.Is that possible?  For example, If a record has 56 columns, I wanted to delete it. I cannot do this for each and every bad record as it takes lot of time and effort.

Can we do this by SSIS?

Comment: So in columns 55 and 56, on bad rows only, you have data? And in those columns, good rows have no data? Why not just apply a filter to hide the records with blanks, the delete all remaining rows?

Comment: Are these 'extra columns' just blank cells you could scan for and remove?  Like if Record 1 has 1,2,3,4,5 and Record 2 has 1,2,3,  ,4,5?

Comment: Probably also worth considering whether you really want to *delete rows that imported incorrectly* or it would be better to *fix the import process in the first place*. I don't know your data and if those rows are just unimportant or not, but you might want to consider making sure all rows import correctly if you want them to.